# How to return a value to the calling function without using return statement?

Tags: c

The function proto type like int xxxx(int) or void xxx(int)

Comment: Why can't you just use `return`?

Comment: This needs to be expanded. The `return` statement _is_ what you use for returning values from functions. What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: The question is a little confusing really. You can use a global variable, but it is not the same as "return value from a function".

Comment: you want to have ruby like notation ?

Comment: My first thought when I read the question was "inline assembly to manipulate the return value and return manually". Maybe I'm thinking about things wrong?

Comment: Can you please elaborate _why_ you can't use `return`? In the comments you say that “we can do in Borland C compiler”—if you _can_, maybe you should post this Borland code to show what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5):

You *could* use a global variable (or, a *little* better, you could use a static variable declared at file scope), or you could change your functions to take an output parameter, but ultimately you should just use a `return` statement, since that's really what it's for.

Answer (score 4):

The two standard ways to return values out of functions in C are to either do it explicitly with the `return` statement, or to use a pointer parameter and assign into the object at the pointer.

There are other ways, but I'm not going into them for fear of increasing the amount of evil code in the world. You should use one of those two.

Answer (score 2):

Use pass by reference:

```
void foo(int* x, int* y) {
 int temp;
 temp = *x;
 x* = *y;
 y* = temp;
}

void main(void) {
 int x = 2, y=4;
 foo(&x, &y);
 printf("Swapped Nums: %d , %d",x,y);
}
```

Comment: You're initialising x and y by converting integers to pointers (implementation defined behaviour) then providing the address of these pointer variables (pointer to pointer to int) to a function expecting pointer to int for both arguments.

Comment: *sigh*. It is a measure of how screwed up C is that manually passing a pointer into C's copy-only parameter mechanisim is considered "passing by reference". A second measure is that your first crack at an example did it wrong, causing who knows what to happen when run. **This answer is *Exhibit A* for why C should be avoided when possible.**

Comment: I supposed to be like: int x=2, y=4;

Comment: i ask how to return a value without using return statement in a function.(instead of return call)

Comment: @Mohamed Saligh, your code is still broken, please fix it. `int *` and `int**` are different types. (And `main` returns `int`.)

Comment: This does not even work as it is, you should have `int temp = *x; *x = *y; *y = temp;`. And the return type of `main` is `int`, not `void`.

Comment: @Mohamed Saligh, congratulations, you've made it worse. Now it doesn't even compile anymore. How can such a broken code be upvoted twice?

Comment: Again, I don't really blame Mohamed. Pointers are just plain error-prone. That's why languages that rely on them for simple everyday tasks like passing reference parameters should be avoided like the plague.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could have a global variable that you assign the value to.
2. You could pass an object that stores the integer, and if you change it in the function, it'll change elsewhere too, since objects are not value type.

It also depends on the programming language that you're using.

EDIT: Sorry I didn't see the C tag, so ignore my last statement

Comment: A more sensible edit would have been to simply erase your last statement, no?

Comment: @Muthuraman - If you can't do #2 there, you don't have a C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you provide a reference to an external variable to your function.

```
void foo(int *value)
{
   *value = 123;
}

int main(void)
{
  int my_return_value = 0;
  foo(&my_return_value);
  printf("Value returned from foo is %d", my_return_value);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Muthuraman - I'm not sure what you are saying there, but this looks like pretty basic standard C to me. It should work just fine on your Borland C compiler.

Comment: how to use another statement instead of return 0; in your code

Comment: @Muthuraman - You're complaining about the return statement at the end of his `main()`? I suppose he could just remove it. Many main's don't bother. However, `return` is a standard part of C, and every function that isn't defined as `void` should be using it. What precisely is your problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is given a prototype like the first one you must use the return statement as the int return value dictates it.

In principle it is possible to do something horrible like cast a pointer to an int and pass it in as a parameter, cast it back and modify it.  As others have alluded to you must be sure you understand all the implications of doing this, and judging by your question I'd say you don't.

Answer (score 0):

int wel();
int main() 
{ 
        int x;
        x = wel();
        printf("%d\n",x);
        return 0;
}
int wel()
{
register int tvr asm ("ax");
        tvr = 77;
}

Compiled with GCC compiler in ubuntu machine. In borland compiler, different way to return.

Comment: Here i am not using return statement.

Comment: And why, oh why, would you want to do this? Serves absolutely no purpose, is not standard C (or even C because it depends on the assembler), utterly non-portable.

Comment: (Philosophically one might also argue that the register is a global variable. =)

Comment: `return` is not a function. But, still, _why_ would you want to do this?

Comment: i agree your comment... We can do instead of return statement

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return more than one value, why not use a pointer to a new allocated struct?

```
typedef struct { int a, char b } mystruct;
mystruct * foo()
{
    mystruct * s = (mystruct *) malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    return s;
}
```

Not tested, but should be valid.